# use outside variable inside of rename() function in R

Tags: r

I'm new to `R` and have a problem

I am trying to reformat some data, and in the process I would like to rename the columns of the new data set.

here is how I have tried to do this:

first the `.csv` file is read in, lets say `case1_case2.csv` 
then the name of the `.csv` file is broken up into two parts 
each part is assigned to a vector
so it ends up being like this:

```
xName=case1
yName=case2
```

After I have put my data into new columns I would like to rename each column to be case1 and case2

to do this I tried using the rename function in `R` but instead of renaming to `case1` and `case2` the columns get renamed to `xName` and `yName`.

here is my code:

```
  for ( n in 1:length(dirNames) ){
      inFile <- read.csv(dirNames[n], header=TRUE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
      xName <- sub("_.*","",dirNames[n])
      yName <- sub(".*[_]([^.]+)[.].*", "\\1", dirNames[n])
      xValues <- inFile %>% select(which(str_detect(names(inFile), xName))) %>% stack() %>% rename( xName = values ) %>% subset( select = xName)
      yValues <- inFile %>% select(which(!str_detect(names(inFile), xName))) %>% stack() %>% rename(yName = values, Organisms=ind)
      finalForm <- cbind(xValues, yValues) %>% filter(complete.cases(.))

}
```

how can I make sure that the variables `xName` and `yName` are expanded inside of the `rename()` function

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't provide a reproducible example, so I'll just demonstrate the idea in general. The `rename` function is part of the `dplyr` package.

You need to "unquote" the variable that contains the string you want to use as the new column name. The unquote operator is `!!` and you'll need to use the special `:=` assignment operator to make unquoting on the left hand side allowed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(x = 1:3)
y <- "Foo"

df %>% rename(y=x)      # Not what you want - need to unquote y
df %>% rename(!!y = x)  # Gives error - need to use :=
df %>% rename(!!y := x) # Correct
```