# SummarySE() function throwing error: Can't rename columns that don't exist. x The column `len` doesn't exist

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

My R version is 3.6.0. I'm trying to use the summarySE() defined here for creating error bars: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

I have used this function many times to plot error bars before. However, when I tried to run the function after updating R I get the following error.

```
 Error: Can't rename columns that don't exist.
x The column `value` doesn't exist.
```

I tried running the sample code on the website (see below) and I get the same error.

```
tg <- ToothGrowth
head(tg)
tgc <- summarySE(tg, measurevar="len", groupvars=c("supp","dose"))
head(tgc)
```

However, when I tried to run the code on an online compiler with R version 3.3.2 it worked. So frustrating!!

Comment: So the sample code actually ran when I install the Rmisc package that summarySE() is a part of. In my code I'm using dplyr, and plyr. I think there must be some conflict because when i run my own code I get the same error.

Comment: The conflict comes with loading plyr and dplyr.. So if you don't load either package and just run the function above, it works. In the Rmisc package, they might have called the function specifically to prevent the clash

Comment: Might be worthwhile to notice the authors of the cookbook :)

Comment: I was having the same problem and it is incredibly furstrating. I explicitly load dplyr, but plyr must be a dependency of some other package I'm loading. I tried using conflicted to try to deal with this.  conflicted_prefer("rename","dplyr")) fails, but conflicted_prefer("rename","plyr") works.  Be great if the authors of the cookbook could make this explicit in their code.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue. It happens because you are trying to use an outside variable inside the rename() function in R. Changing this line:

```
datac <- rename(datac, c("mean" = measurevar))
```

to

```
datac <- rename(datac, !!measurevar := mean)
```

fixed the issue for me. See this link for more details. [use outside variable inside of rename() function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525880/use-outside-variable-inside-of-rename-function-in-r)